# ScrollView with image and text not scrolling in android

Tags: android, react-native

I'm new to RN, not sure why this very simple Component with just an Image and some Text doesn't scroll. I suspect the first Text "title here" could be the problem.

```
class ScrollContent extends Component {
state = {}

componentDidMount(){
    console.log("about componentDidMount")
}
render() {
    const { params } = this.props.navigation.state;
    return (
        <View style={{flex: 1}}>
        <ScrollView>
            <Image
                source={require('./../img/about.jpg')}
                style={{height:"40%",resizeMode: 'cover'}}
            />

 <Text style={{
                fontSize: 22,
                color:"white",
                backgroundColor:"red",
                paddingTop:20,
                paddingBottom:20,
                paddingLeft:10,
                paddingRight:10
            }}
            >title here</Text>
            <Text style={styles.text}>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Vivamus vulputate diam a euismod euismod. Nullam sagittis pellentesque sem, eu vestibulum diam. Mauris eget egestas quam. Nunc fringilla magna id egestas semper. Mauris aliquet justo a vestibulum malesuada.</Text>

            <Text style={styles.text}>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Vivamus vulputate diam a euismod euismod. Nullam sagittis pellentesque sem, eu vestibulum diam. Mauris eget egestas quam. Nunc fringilla magna id egestas semper.</Text>
        </ScrollView>
        </View>
    );
}
}
```

Comment: I think your content might be too small for the `ScrollView` to scroll, Also try supplying the `height` to the image based on the `Dimensions` of the screen since, `scrollview` works differently.

Comment: indeed the problem was the missing height in Image. Could you post an answer so I can mark as accepted?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since the Scroll in the `Android` is not **Inertial** as `IOS`,

therefore you wont be able to visualise the scroll if the elements contained in your `ScrollView` have a `total height` less that the `screen height`.

Also another point to note you need to supply the height of the Image based on the `Dimensions` of the screen, since `ScrollView` behaviour differs from the View behaviour

*Hope it helps*